# WPF событие тригера на клик

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Какое событие в тригерах отвечает за клик? Хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на картинку она увеличивалась, а при отпускании нажатия уменьшалась.

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `EventTrigger`, я покажу на примере `TextBlock`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 To="32" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 To="13" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" FontSize="13"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Animation]